# Why Amazon EC2 is not accessible using ping?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've been using AWS for a few months without any problem. But from yesterday, I can't access the website. When I ping the IP (52.24.23.108) it displays request time out. Server's status is okay - that I checked from AWS console. Isn't it a network problem of Amazon Webservices?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the specified network traffic type (ICMP) through your security groups for your instance. You can do this by choosing *Security Groups* > select your security group and choose *Edit Inbound Rules*

Choose "ICMP" from the dropdown and source (* if you want it from everywhere) then *Add Rule*

PINGs should work!

Answer (score 0):

A couple things could cause this, most likely you provisioned the instance with a public IP, by NOT a n elastic IP. If you had a server restart, either by your doing or by AWS, then your public IP would be dropped. If you did use a elastic IP, then look at your security group to see if you allow icmp still or if the security group changed.

Another cause may be if a server level firewall had been disabled in the past, but if your server went through a restart it may have started again. What base OS are you using?